# The longest length of most consecutive number which is bigger than zero in a series

Tags: arrays, sql-server, t-sql, series

I wanna write a t-sql query which will return the longest length of  most consecutive number which is bigger than zero in a series
for example: I have the below dataset

```
create table samples(
  id int, 
  num1 int, num2 int, num3 int, num4 int, num5 int, 
  num6 int, num7 int, num8 int, num9 int, num10 int
);
insert into samples values
  (1, 1, 1 , 0, 0 , 0, 1, 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 ),
  (2, 1, 1 , 1, 1 , 0, 1, 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 ),
  (3, 0, 1 , 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 );
```

The data represents activation based on months.(For 10 months). I'd like to get longest active time period through 10 months.
For `id=1` there are two 1 at the beginning and three 1 following some zeros, for this id I'd like the get the three as result.
For `id=2` there are four 1 at the beginning and three 1 after a zero, for this id I,'d like to get 4 as result. 
And for `id = 3` I'd like to get 3  as well. 
And since max value is 1 in series, it occurs in two different consecutive places and first one has 2 as length and second is 3.

Comment: Try unpivoting the columns (with UNPIVOT) and then using a running sum (with SUM ... OVER) to find the longest periods.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to concatenate a string of 1's an 0's, then use `string_split()` on the zero to get the max duration

This assumes ones an zeros.  If other values use can use `sign(num1)` or even `left(num1,1)`

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,MaxLen = max(len(B.value))
 From samples A
 Cross Apply string_split(concat(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10),'0') B
 Group By ID
```

**Returns**

```
ID  MaxLen
1   3
2   4
3   3
```

> **EDIT - Perhaps a more Performant version**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.MaxLen
 From samples A
 Cross Apply (Select MaxLen = max(len(value)) 
               From  string_split(concat(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10),'0') 
             ) B
```

Comment: Very slick, I like it!